# Let $f,g$ integrals function in $\left[a,b\right]$, Prove $(\int_{a}^{b}fg)^{2}\leq(\int_{a}^{b}f^{2})(\int_{a}^{b}g^{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f,g$ integrals function in $\left[a,b\right]$, Prove $\left(\int_{a}^{b}fg\right)^{2}\leq(\int_{a}^{b}f^{2})(\int_{a}^{b}g^{2})$

I try this:

We know

$0\leq(f-\lambda g)^{2}=f^{2}-2\lambda fg+g^{2}$ with $\lambda$ in $\mathbb R$

Then:

$0\leq\int f^{2}-2\lambda\int_{a}^{b}fg+\lambda^{2}\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}$

In this step i'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: If a 2nd degree polynomial is always positive, then what can you say about its discriminant?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to prove is the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: Assuming that $\int_a^b g^2 > 0$, choose $\Lambda = (\int_a^b fg)/(\int_a^b g^2)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can finish the proof using Oussama's comment.

We have a quadratic polynomial $a\Lambda^2+b\Lambda+c$ for fixed real values $a=\int f^2$, $\ b=-2\int fg$, $\ c=\int g^2$.

If such a polynomial is *always* greater or equal than $0$, that means it has no or at most one real root, and as such, its *discriminant* $b^2-4ac$ must be $\le 0$, which will just give the result to be proved.